# Fonts in vuetify template, how change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my Vue project file index.html add this text:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
```

add in component toolbar from Vuetify, but in toolbar displayed incorrect

How i change font in toolbar?

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="lime accent-1" height="60px">
    <v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-icon>android</v-icon>
    </v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down abc">
      <v-btn flat>Signup</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Login</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used **scoped** style so it will only apply to the elements of its parent(s) and children. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)

In your case you'd need to apply a class to your **v-toolbar** element as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="lime accent-1" height="60px" class="change-font">
    <v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-icon>android</v-icon>
    </v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down abc">
      <v-btn flat>Signup</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Login</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.change-font {
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is that your components have no reference to the imported font.

For vuetify, I add the npm packages for roboto-fontface, material-design-icons, then import them into my main.js (if you are using webpack).

```
import 'roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css';
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
```

And then vuetify will be able to access these natively, without referencing styles.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem - had the link in the index.html but roboto was not showing up

My problem was the way I'd imported vuetify in `plugins/vuetify.ts`

Incorrect import

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
```

Correct import

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
```